# Font problem: Coelacanth Italics

Tags: fonts

I use Ben Whitmore's excellent http://benwhitmore.altervista.org/coelacanth-type-family/Coelacanth font in org-mode. The font family is provided in several OTF files.

Setting
`xfthb:-PfEd-Coelacanth-light-normal-normal-*-22-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1`
as `variable-pitch` works well and looks good.

But I'm unable to set the `italic` face to Coelacanth's Italic. I tried the `Customize Face` dialogue, I tried Lisp expressions with variations of the `xfthb` string above, with one or more `normal`s substituted with `italic`, but the result looks like (and is, by `C-u C-x =`) the uninitializied version.

Answer (score 0):

Totally unintuitive, but works:

```
(create-fontset-from-fontset-spec
    "-PfEd-Coelacanth-normal-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-fontset-custom")
(set-face-attribute 'italic nil :font "fontset-custom")
```

Comment: I *blindly* tried the above snippet on `GNU Emacs 29.0.50 dtd build date 2022-06-11`.  `Emacs` gives me a `*Backtrace*`.  Either we are using a different font files, or we are using different OS-es, or `Emacs` has moved since .  For those looking into generating custom fontsets,  a better starting point would be https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/70338/31220.   Honestly speaking, I don't understand what is being discussed, but I know for sure that strings like **"-PfEd-Coelacanth-normal-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-fontset-custom"** is the last thing an ordinary user like me would like to see.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**:

1. Emacs gives primacy to the `font family` name.  This is in spite of the fact that the `Menu Bar -> Options -> Set Default Font` displays the `Font Name` and NOT the `Family Name`.
2. None of the `Coelacanth` font files, defines slant property.  So, it is not surprising that `Emacs` doesn't honour the `italic` property requested in `slant` property.

---

I installed `Coelacanth` font from http://benwhitmore.altervista.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Coelacanth20140829.zip. See [Coelacanth: a type family inspired by Bruce Rogers' Centaur](http://benwhitmore.altervista.org/coelacanth-type-family/).

I set the default font using `Menu Bar -> Options -> Set Default Font` as below

[image: Set Default Font to Coelacanth Italic]

The default font wasn't typeset in Italic.

To investigate this behaviour further, I `eval`-led the following forms

```lisp
(face-attribute 'default :font)
```

```
=> 

   #<font-object "-PfEd-Coelacanth-medium-normal-normal-*-15-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1">
```

```lisp
(font-info (face-attribute 'default :font))
```

```lisp
=> 

   ["-PfEd-Coelacanth-medium-normal-normal-*-15-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
 "Coelacanth:pixelsize=15:foundry=PfEd:weight=medium:slant=normal:width=normal:scalable=true"
 15 20 0 0 0 17 14 6 3 7 "~/.local/share/fonts/Coelac_R14.otf"
 (opentype
  ...)]
```

You can see that font file used is `Coelac_R14.otf`, and the fontspec doesn't have any italic in it.

Then I did this

```
~$ echo "|%{fullname}| %{file} | %{foundry} | %{family}| %{slant}|\n"; fc-list -f "|%{fullname} |%{file} | %{foundry} | %{family}| %{slant}|\n" | grep 'Coela' 

| %{fullname}             | %{file}        | %{foundry} | %{family}          | %{slant} |
| Coelacanth_Regular 24op | Coelac_R24.otf | PfEd       | Coelacanth         |        0 |
| CoelacanthLight 14op    | Coelac_L14.otf | PfEd       | CoelacanthLight    |        0 |
| CoelacanthSemibold 14op | Coelac_S14.otf | PfEd       | CoelacanthSemibold |        0 |
| CoelacanthLight 4op     | Coelac_L4.otf  | PfEd       | CoelacanthLight    |        0 |
| CoelacanthLight 6op     | Coelac_L6.otf  | PfEd       | CoelacanthLight    |        0 |
| CoelacanthHeavy 14op    | Coelac_H14.otf | PfEd       | CoelacanthHeavy    |        0 |
| Coelacanth_Bold 8op     | Coelac_B8.otf  | PfEd       | Coelacanth         |        0 |
| Coelacanth_Regular 14op | Coelac_R14.otf | PfEd       | Coelacanth         |        0 |
| Coelacanth_Bold 6op     | Coelac_B6.otf  | PfEd       | Coelacanth         |        0 |
| Coelacanth_Bold 4op     | Coelac_B4.otf  | PfEd       | Coelacanth         |        0 |
| CoelacanthLight_8op     | Coelac_L8.otf  | PfEd       | CoelacanthLight    |        0 |
| Coelacanth_Bold 14op    | Coelac_B14.otf | PfEd       | Coelacanth         |        0 |
| CoelacanthSemibold_6op  | Coelac_S6.otf  | PfEd       | CoelacanthSemibold |        0 |
| CoelacanthSemibold_8op  | Coelac_S8.otf  | PfEd       | CoelacanthSemibold |        0 |
| Coelacanth_Regular 60op | Coelac_R60.otf | PfEd       | Coelacanth         |        0 |
| Coelacanth Italic       | Coelac14-I.otf | PfEd       | Coelacanth         |        0 |
| CoelacanthSemibold 4op  | Coelac_S4.otf  | PfEd       | CoelacanthSemibold |        0 |
| Coelacanth_Regular 6op  | Coelac_R6.otf  | PfEd       | Coelacanth         |        0 |
| Coelacanth_Regular 4op  | Coelac_R4.otf  | PfEd       | Coelacanth         |        0 |
| Coelacanth_Regular 8op  | Coelac_R8.otf  | PfEd       | Coelacanth         |        0 |
```

There are 2 things you can notice in above output

1. The  `Coelacanth Italic` comes from `Coelac14-I.otf`.  It's family name is `Coelacanth`
2. The `slant` of the font is `0`.

The reason that `Emacs` is not picking up this font file, is because the font file doesn't declare the `slant` property.  (When you set up `italic` face, Emacs is essentially looking for a `font-entity` that defines the `slant`.)

So, what I did was open the font file, which was providing the `italic` font, but NOT the `slant` property, and fixed the `font family` as below.

```
~$ fontforge ~/.local/share/fonts/Coelac14-I.otf
```

[image: In Fontforge, change Family Name to Coelacanth Italic]

followed by `Fontforge -> Menu bar -> File -> Generate Fonts`.

Then I updated the font cache with,

```
$ fc-cache -f -v
```

I restarted Emacs, set the default font---`Menu bar -> Options -> Set Default Font`---to one of the `Coelacanth` fonts.

Then I did, `M-x customize-face RET italic` as before and I applied the changes.

[image: Use the newly defined Coelocanth Italic family for `italic face]

---

[Font configuration - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/font_configuration) claims the following

> **Create bold and italic styles for incomplete fonts**

> FreeType has the ability to automatically create italic and bold styles for fonts that do not have them, but only if explicitly required by the application.

Since `Emacs` is a very old beast, I wouldn't be surprised if `Emacs` goes an extra step in creating `italic` style out of "incomplete" fonts.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to original question is here https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/72415/31220.

This is some supplemental `elisp` helpers that I used to make some sense of what `Emacs` is doing underneath ...

#### Snippets to look at `font family` and their component `font`s

```lisp
;; See `mouse-generate-font-menu'
(require 'dash)
(->> (font-family-list)
     (--filter (string-match-p "Coelacanth" it)) ; change the family name, if requried
     -uniq
     (--map
      (cons it
        (if nil       ; flip this to t, for simpler result
        (x-family-fonts it)
          (->> (list-fonts (font-spec :family it))
           (--map (list it :name (or (font-get it :name)
                         (mouse-generate-font-name-for-menu it))
                :xlfd-name (font-xlfd-name it))))))))
```

which gives me

```lisp
(("CoelacanthSemibold"
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb PfEd CoelacanthSemibold nil iso10646-1 semi-bold normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/Coelac_S4.otf" . 0))
         > :name "semi-bold" :xlfd-name "-PfEd-CoelacanthSemibold-semibold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb PfEd CoelacanthSemibold nil iso10646-1 semi-bold normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/Coelac_S6.otf" . 0))
         > :name "semi-bold" :xlfd-name "-PfEd-CoelacanthSemibold-semibold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb PfEd CoelacanthSemibold nil iso10646-1 semi-bold normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/Coelac_S8.otf" . 0))
         > :name "semi-bold" :xlfd-name "-PfEd-CoelacanthSemibold-semibold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb PfEd CoelacanthSemibold nil iso10646-1 semi-bold normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/Coelac_S14.otf" . 0))
         > :name "semi-bold" :xlfd-name "-PfEd-CoelacanthSemibold-semibold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"))
 ("CoelacanthLight"
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb PfEd CoelacanthLight nil iso10646-1 light normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/Coelac_L8.otf" . 0))
         > :name "light" :xlfd-name "-PfEd-CoelacanthLight-light-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb PfEd CoelacanthLight nil iso10646-1 light normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/Coelac_L6.otf" . 0))
         > :name "light" :xlfd-name "-PfEd-CoelacanthLight-light-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb PfEd CoelacanthLight nil iso10646-1 light normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/Coelac_L4.otf" . 0))
         > :name "light" :xlfd-name "-PfEd-CoelacanthLight-light-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb PfEd CoelacanthLight nil iso10646-1 light normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/Coelac_L14.otf" . 0))
         > :name "light" :xlfd-name "-PfEd-CoelacanthLight-light-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"))
 ("Coelacanth Italic"
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb PfEd Coelacanth\ Italic nil iso10646-1 medium normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/Coelac-I.ttf" . 0))
         > :name "medium" :xlfd-name "-PfEd-Coelacanth Italic-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"))
 ("Coelacanth"
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb PfEd Coelacanth nil iso10646-1 medium normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/Coelac_R4.otf" . 0))
         > :name "medium" :xlfd-name "-PfEd-Coelacanth-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb PfEd Coelacanth nil iso10646-1 regular normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/Coelac_R6.otf" . 0))
         > :name "regular" :xlfd-name "-PfEd-Coelacanth-regular-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb PfEd Coelacanth nil iso10646-1 regular normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/Coelac_R24.otf" . 0))
         > :name "regular" :xlfd-name "-PfEd-Coelacanth-regular-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb PfEd Coelacanth nil iso10646-1 bold normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/Coelac_B14.otf" . 0))
         > :name "bold" :xlfd-name "-PfEd-Coelacanth-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb PfEd Coelacanth nil iso10646-1 medium normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/Coelac_R14.otf" . 0))
         > :name "medium" :xlfd-name "-PfEd-Coelacanth-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb PfEd Coelacanth nil iso10646-1 regular normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/Coelac_R8.otf" . 0))
         > :name "regular" :xlfd-name "-PfEd-Coelacanth-regular-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb PfEd Coelacanth nil iso10646-1 medium normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/Coelac14-I.otf" . 0))
         > :name "medium" :xlfd-name "-PfEd-Coelacanth-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb PfEd Coelacanth nil iso10646-1 bold normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/Coelac_B8.otf" . 0))
         > :name "bold" :xlfd-name "-PfEd-Coelacanth-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb PfEd Coelacanth nil iso10646-1 bold normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/Coelac_B4.otf" . 0))
         > :name "bold" :xlfd-name "-PfEd-Coelacanth-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb PfEd Coelacanth nil iso10646-1 bold normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/Coelac_B6.otf" . 0))
         > :name "bold" :xlfd-name "-PfEd-Coelacanth-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb PfEd Coelacanth nil iso10646-1 medium normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/Coelac_R60.otf" . 0))
         > :name "medium" :xlfd-name "-PfEd-Coelacanth-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"))
 ("CoelacanthHeavy"
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb PfEd CoelacanthHeavy nil iso10646-1 black normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/Coelac_H14.otf" . 0))
         > :name "black" :xlfd-name "-PfEd-CoelacanthHeavy-black-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")))
```