# How can I apply a user-defined fontset to a face?

Tags: faces, fonts, fontsets

Say I create a fontset and populate it with fonts:

```
(create-fontset-from-fontset-spec
 (font-xlfd-name (font-spec :registry "fontset-mine")))
(set-fontset-font "fontset-mine" 'latin "Noto Serif")
(set-fontset-font "fontset-mine" 'kana "Noto Serif CJK JP")
```

I can't find a way to get a face to use this fontset.  For example, if I set it like `(set-face-attribute 'my-test-face nil :font "fontset-mine")`, then `my-test-face` will show `kana` scripts in Noto Sans CJK *KR*, not JP (presumably a fallback specified by `fontset-standard` or something).

According to [investigations by Yuan Fu](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=49797), when `set-face-attribute` or similar is given a fontset as `:font`, it merely extracts the ASCII font of that set and copies its family, height, etc. onto the face  (corroborated by a comparison of `describe-face` before and after `set-face-attribute`).  This means I can't use it to set more than one font to a face simultaneously; anything not supported by the one font that is set, will use some Emacs-wide fallback.  The bug report talks about setting the `:fontset` attribute, but that doesn't seem to do anything either.  (EDIT: this last statement was wrong; see the answer.)

So my question is: is there a way to apply user-defined fontsets to any faces?  By user-defined, I mean those created in `init.el` with `create-fontset-from-fontset-spec`, as opposed to built-in ones like `fontset-standard`.  If not, are user-defined fontsets useful for anything?

My particular use case is as follows.  I want to switch between these sets of fonts, depending on the type of document I'm editing.

- ETbb for `latin`, Noto Serif CJK JP for `kana`.
- Noto Sans for `latin`, Noto Sans CJK JP for `kana`.

(There are lots more scripts I'm interested in, but I'll focus on two.)  Right now I can produce a face that has any of the following, none of which is what I want.

- ETbb for `latin` and some fallback font for `kana`
- Noto Sans for `latin` and some fallback font for `kana`
- Some fallback font for `latin` and Noto Serif CJK JP for `kana`
- Some fallback font for `latin` and Noto Sans CJK JP for `kana`

The point is, without a way to apply a fontset as one indivisible unit, I can only control `latin` or `kana`, not both; one of them will get specified by default, not by me.

Comment: What does `describe-fontset` show you for your new fontset?

Comment: @db48x It shows `C-@ .. DEL -*-Noto Serif-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*` for ASCII and `぀ .. ヿ (#x3040 .. #x30FF) -*-Noto Serif CJK JP-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*` for Japanese, so `set-fontset-font` is working as it should, AFAICT.  (FYI, a sample kana is あ at #x3042)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this stuff. But did you try `set-face-font`? It sets attribute `:font`, whose value can be a font **or a fontset**.

Comment: I think the doc in the Elisp manual isn't obvious enough about the value of `:font` being able to be a fontset. But that seems to be what lets a face have different fonts for different chars. I filed Emacs bug [#53664](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=53664) to improve this aspect of the manual.

Comment: @Drew Thanks, I hadn't considered `set-face-font`.  Unfortunately, it's the same deal as setting `:font` with `set-face-attribute`.  The doc is wrong in this respect.

Comment: It almost seems like the people who implemented this stuff were planning on making fontset usable just like fonts.  They initially settled on this ASCII extraction as a temporary measure, but then stuff happened and it got forgotten.  That's just speculation, but in any case, it looks like the maintainers right now don't have the resources to overhaul the code to match the docs, so perhaps retracting that statement on the docs is the most prudent thing to do.

Comment: I see from your answer that your previous comment about it not working was mistaken. You can delete comments, if you like, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yikes.  I had a fresh look at this after a good night's sleep, and it turns out I was wrong to say that setting the `:fontset` attribute doesn't work.  My test code had a critical typo, and I also tried `custom-theme-set-faces` etc. in addition to `set-face-attribute`, and then mixed things up.  Sorry for the confusion.

To set the record straight:

- You can apply a fontset to a face by setting its `:fontset` attribute with `set-face-attribute`.  The face will then use all fonts in the set as expected.  EDIT: the values of `:font`, `:family` etc. override `:fontset`, so if you're modifying a pre-existing face like `variable-pitch`, be sure to adjust those other attributes as well.
- However, you cannot set the `:fontset` attribute using `custom-theme-set-faces` or `defface`, which ignore that attribute.
- The manual currently says in some places that you can pass in a fontset for the `:font` attribute or the font argument of `set-face-font`, but this is misleading at best: the fontset will be stripped of the "set" part and be treated as just an ASCII font.

I think the second bullet means that there's no way to enable/disable fontsets with themes, but someone more knowledgeable on themes will have to set me straight on this.

Comment: You can accept your own answer, BTW.