# Faces become italic automatically

Tags: fonts

I'm trying to set default face to use `PingFang Mono SC` font. But I notice that faces that don't use this font become italic unexpectedly. As one can see below the `font-lock-comment-face` is italic, but it is not set to be (it's only set to use `SF Pro` family).

The only weird part I notice is that the "oblique" word in `describe-char` on the `PingFang Mono SC` font (see the 3rd image below), as one can see the font do have a regular variant. I don't understand what's happening here and how it affects other faces that don't use this font (notice that "italic" is found in the `describe-char` buffer of `SF Pro` font in the 1st image).

As you can see the test config below, I do not set any italic related things.

I've tested it in an `emacs -q` session.

I don't has this issue with other mono fonts for `default` face.

How can I set `default` face to use `PingFang Mono SC` font but without this unexpected italic issue?

[image: Call describe-char on T of the word this]

(Notice the "italic" word in the second window, I didn't set it.)

[image]

(The `font-lock-comment-face` is not set to be italic.)

[image]

(Notice the "oblique" word in the second window, I don't know why it is.)

[image]

(The information of `PingFang Mono SC` font.)

[image]

(The information of `SF Pro` font.)

[image]

(As for comparison, the issue does not happen when using other mono fonts for `default` face. As one can see in this case, the default face is set to `DM Mono`, but `font-lock-comment-face` is normal. Also notice the "normal-normal-normal" part for `SF Pro`. Everything is just fine.)

Minimal test config:

```
;; This buffer is for text that is not saved, and for Lisp evaluation.
;; To create a file, visit it with C-x C-f and enter text in its buffer.

(when (display-graphic-p)
  (set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "PingFang Mono SC")
  (custom-set-faces '(font-lock-comment-face ((t (:family "SF Pro"))))))
```

- The `PingFang Mono SC` font is downloaded from [here](https://eng.fontke.com/family/1410889/).
- The `SF Pro` font comes with system.
- OS: macOS 12.5 (21G72)
- Emacs: GNU Emacs 28.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin21.5.0, Carbon Version 165 AppKit 2113.5) of 2022-07-04

Comment: There is a lot of information in your post, but I am unsure of what your question is. Could you please clarify your question? Are you asking "Why does switching to this font cause others to default to italics and how do I prevent this behaviour?" or "How do I ensure that faces with this font that are set to italics are displayed in italics within Emacs?" or "Where can I find out how Emacs utilizes fonts for faces?" Also, your bounty is for a canonical answer. Could you clarify what you are looking for in the answer?

Comment: @MalleYeno Hi, when I set `PingFang Mono SC` font for the `default` face, other faces like `font-lock-comment-face` that are set to use other fonts become italic unexpectedly. I'm not sure how can this happens (Notice that I didn't set any italic related things for `default` and `font-lock-comment-face`). I want a way to figure out what's happening and fix this issue. And I don't have this issue with other fonts so I post the link where I got this font.

Comment: @MalleYeno I also updated the question, I hope the issue is clearer...

Comment: Can you explain how did you get this Emacs version? the word "Carbon" stands for "Carbon(API)" display engine, deprecated since 2009. Actually in use is the Cocoa(API), shown as "NS appkit" in emacs-version string.

Comment: @lan I installed it by `brew install --with-dbus --with-rsvg --with-natural-title-bar --with-mac-metal --with-glib --with-imagemagick`.

Comment: @lan You reminded me that I should test in a different Emacs version. The issue also exists in emacs-plus installed by `brew install emacs-plus --with-debug --with-xwidgets --with-no-frame-refocus --with-imagemagick --with-dbus --with-mailutils`.

Comment: What theme do you use? it would be useful to know the real configuration. Some theme by default use italics for comments (e.g. see the code for Leuven theme), some other may be configured to use italics (e.g. modus-operandi).

Comment: @lan I don't use themes. The snippet in the question description is the real configuration. Everything is tested under `emacs -q`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```lisp
(create-fontset-from-fontset-spec
 (font-xlfd-name (font-spec :registry "fontset-mine" :family "SF Pro"
                :weight 'regular :slant 'normal :width 'normal)))

(set-face-attribute 'font-lock-comment-face nil :font "fontset-mine")
```

---

On Debian, I see `regular` in `xfld-name`.  But looking at your screenshots I see `normal`.  So try tweaking the `:weight` to either `regular` or `normal` to match the the `xfld-name` that gives you  the desired face properties.

Docstring for `font-spec` says a value of `regular`, `normal` and `book` for weight is equivalent, but the `xfld` string generated depends on the value passed to `:weight` property

```
*** Welcome to IELM ***  Type (describe-mode) or press C-h m for help.
ELISP> (create-fontset-from-fontset-spec
    (font-xlfd-name 
     (font-spec  
      :registry "fontset-mine" 
      :family "SF Pro"
      :weight 'regular 
      :slant 'normal
      :width 'normal)))
"-*-sf pro-regular-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-fontset-mine"
ELISP> (create-fontset-from-fontset-spec
    (font-xlfd-name 
     (font-spec  
      :registry "fontset-mine" 
      :family "SF Pro"
      :weight 'normal
      :slant 'normal
      :width 'normal)))
"-*-sf pro-normal-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-fontset-mine"
ELISP>
```

It is possible that the name of the weight portion--`regular` or `normal`--matters and makes a difference.  So, specify them explicitly instead of using wildcards.

---

I have used `SF Pro` in my examples, you could try the same diagnostics on `Ping Fang Mono` font files.  Note that I am trying with Debian, so you may have to make some adjustments to the strings based on what the Mac side (or Windows) reports.

Comment: This answer works for the original issue. But when I try to use `fontset-mine` in `buffer-face-set`, I can not change the height of the font, e.g. `(buffer-face-set :family "fontset-mine" :height 150)`.

Comment: Have you tried `1.50` instead of `150`.  Do you want both the comment and regular text to be of different heights, or you want the whole buffer to be scaled to 1.50 ....  I can scale just the comment face with `(set-face-attribute 'font-lock-comment-face nil :font "fontset-mine" :height 1.50)`.  Ensure that scaling works with regular config, before moving on to `buffer-face-mode`.

Comment: `buffer-face-set` basically does   `(face-remap-add-relative 'default buffer-face-mode-face)`.   It overlays the the `default` font with `buffer-face-mode-face`.  How have you configured the `bufffer-face-mode-face`?  In your case, the `default` and `font-lock-comment-face` uses different `font-family`.  So, you may have to experiment with `face-remap-add-relative` on both the `default` and `font-lock-comment-face`, I guess ...

Comment: `(buffer-face-set :height 1.50)` works for me.

Comment: Sorry and I'm trying to clarify the problem. Let's call `fontset-mine` as a fixed version of `SF Pro`...Due to the original issue exists, I need this fixed version for some faces like `font-lock-comment-face`in my `prog-mode` buffers. But I also use a variable font (originally `SF Pro`) in `org-mode` with a larger font size. With this fixed `fontset-mine`, I can not tweak its size. `(buffer-face-set :family "fontset-mine" :height 1.50)` does not work for me (The font size becomes large, but it does not recognize the font correctly. It uses `Helvetica` instead as a fallback option).

Comment: `(buffer-face-set :height 1.50)` works for setting font size, but it does not tell `org-mode` to use a variable font (I set this in `org-mode-hook` before).

Comment: I am no longer sure what you are trying to do (whether you are trying to have different faces for default and comments etc) Close this question, and post a fresh question with the configuration you have settled on ...

Comment: Done [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/73078/buffer-face-mode-does-not-work-with-custom-fontset).

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I see no issues with Debian/Linux.

---

Try identifying the `xfld-name` that does NOT have italic in description. (In your question you have already identified a fontspec that is "normal" or "regular" as opposed to "italic" or "oblique".  If not use the following `elisp` code to identify the `xfld` strings

```lisp
(require 'dash)
(->> (font-family-list)
     (--filter (string-match-p "SF Pro" it)) ; change the family name, if requried
     -uniq
     (--map
      (cons it
        (if nil       ; flip this to t, for simpler result
        (x-family-fonts it)
          (->> (list-fonts (font-spec :family it))
               (--map (font-xlfd-name it) ))))))
```

```lisp
(("SF Pro"
  "-APPL-SF Pro-thin-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro-black-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro-semibold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro-regular-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro-thin-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro-black-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro-light-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  )
 ("SF Pro Rounded"
  "-APPL-SF Pro Rounded-semibold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro Rounded-regular-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro Rounded-black-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro Rounded-semibold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro Rounded-extrabold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro Rounded-light-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro Rounded-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro Rounded-thin-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro Rounded-ultralight-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  )
 ("SF Pro Display"
  "-APPL-SF Pro Display-thin-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro Display-black-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro Display-semibold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro Display-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro Display-regular-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro Display-semibold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro Display-extrabold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro Display-light-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro Display-ultralight-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  )
 ("SF Pro Text"
  "-APPL-SF Pro Text-thin-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro Text-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro Text-semibold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro Text-black-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro Text-regular-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro Text-ultralight-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro Text-light-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro Text-extrabold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-SF Pro Text-semibold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  ))
```

In the above list, replace the `iso10646-1` part with `fontset-xxx`; it doesn't matter what `xxx` happens to be.  (See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/73067/31220 if you want to do away with manually editing out the `iso10646-1` part, and replacing it with a fontset name)

Then explicity set the `:font` property of `font-lock-comment-face`, as below

```lisp
;; fontset-1 uses regular

(create-fontset-from-fontset-spec
 "-APPL-SF Pro-regular-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-fontset-1")

(set-face-attribute 'font-lock-comment-face nil :font "fontset-1")
```

```lisp
;; fontset-2 uses italic

(create-fontset-from-fontset-spec
 "-APPL-SF Pro-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-fontset-2")

(set-face-attribute 'font-lock-comment-face nil :font "fontset-2")
```

```lisp
;; fontset-3 uses bold
(create-fontset-from-fontset-spec
 "-APPL-SF Pro-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-fontset-3")

(set-face-attribute 'font-lock-comment-face nil :font "fontset-3")
```

Comment: When I try the code snippet for `PingFang Mono SC`, I get `(("PingFang Mono SC"
 "-*-PingFang Mono SC-normal-oblique-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1"
 "-*-PingFang Mono SC-bold-oblique-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1"))`. There no `normal-normal-normal` for it. Maybe there's some issue of this font?

Comment: This is what I get `(("PingFang Mono SC"
  "-APPL-PingFang Mono SC-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"
  "-APPL-PingFang Mono SC-regular-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"))`.  Which OS are you in?  I downloaded the MacOS versions of the fonts, only yesterday.  Have you looked at the output from `fc-list`? As noted in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/72415/31220, the `Coelocanth` font was using italic style, but the font file wasn't declaring the slant property.  Use `fontforge` on `PingFang` font file to see if something is amiss ...

Comment: `| %{fullname}              | %{file}                                         | %{foundry} | %{family}        | %{slant} | \n |
|--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+------------+------------------+----------+----|
| PingFang Mono SC Bold    | ~/.local/share/fonts/PingFangMonoSC-Bold.ttf    | APPL       | PingFang Mono SC |        0 |    |
| PingFang Mono SC Regular | ~/.local/share/fonts/PingFangMonoSC-Regular.ttf | APPL       | PingFang Mono SC |        0 |    | `  The foundry in my case is APPL. I suspect you have downloaded the `windows` version

Comment: I'm using macOS 12.5. The OS itself does not ship with the mono version of `PingFang`. So I got the font from the link in the original post. I don't seem to find other available places for the font. Where did you get the font? The `fc-list` result is `|%{fullname}| %{file} | %{foundry} | %{family}| %{slant}|\n
|PingFang Mono SC Regular |/Users/User/Library/Fonts/PingFangMonoSC-Regular.ttf | APPL | PingFang Mono SC| 0|
|PingFang Mono SC Bold |/Users/User/Library/Fonts/PingFangMonoSC-Bold.ttf | APPL | PingFang Mono SC| 0|`.

Comment: The Slant is 0 in your output.  I downloaded it from the link.  May be they revised the font files since you downloaded.  If I were you, I wouldn't worry about the font file, as long as I get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested answer is here https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/73065/31220 or here https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/73067/31220.

This is some supplementary information for the above answer.  This is the infomration I obtained for `SF Pro` fonts.  I have done a similar exercise for `Coelacanth` font.  See all my comments under [Font problem: Coelacanth Italics](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/64740/font-problem-coelacanth-italics)

This is not an answer, but a comment ...

Hopefully it will give you leads

### Try to identify the font file that provides *non-zero* `slant` attribute

```
$ echo "|%{fullname}| %{file} | %{foundry} | %{family}| %{slant}|\n"; fc-list -f "|%{fullname} |%{file} | %{foundry} | %{family}| %{slant}|\n" | grep 'SF Pro'
```

```
| %{fullname}                      | %{file}                             | %{foundry} | %{family}      | %{slant} | \n |
| SF Pro Text Regular              | SF-Pro-Text-Regular.otf             | APPL       | SF Pro Text    |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Italic                    | SF-Pro-Italic.ttf                   | APPL       | SF Pro         |      100 |    |
| SF Pro Text Light Italic         | SF-Pro-Text-LightItalic.otf         | APPL       | SF Pro Text    |      100 |    |
| SF Pro Display Black Italic      | SF-Pro-Display-BlackItalic.otf      | APPL       | SF Pro Display |      100 |    |
| SF Pro Rounded Semibold          | SF-Pro-Rounded-Semibold.otf         | APPL       | SF Pro Rounded |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Text Heavy                | SF-Pro-Text-Heavy.otf               | APPL       | SF Pro Text    |        0 |    |
| SF Pro                           | SF-Pro.ttf                          | APPL       | SF Pro         |        0 |    |
| SF Pro                           | SF-Pro.ttf                          | APPL       | SF Pro         |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Display Regular Italic    | SF-Pro-Display-RegularItalic.otf    | APPL       | SF Pro Display |      100 |    |
| SF Pro Italic                    | SF-Pro-Italic.ttf                   | APPL       | SF Pro         |      100 |    |
| SF Pro Text Light                | SF-Pro-Text-Light.otf               | APPL       | SF Pro Text    |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Display Light Italic      | SF-Pro-Display-LightItalic.otf      | APPL       | SF Pro Display |      100 |    |
| SF Pro Rounded Heavy             | SF-Pro-Rounded-Heavy.otf            | APPL       | SF Pro Rounded |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Display Medium            | SF-Pro-Display-Medium.otf           | APPL       | SF Pro Display |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Display Heavy             | SF-Pro-Display-Heavy.otf            | APPL       | SF Pro Display |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Text Semibold Italic      | SF-Pro-Text-SemiboldItalic.otf      | APPL       | SF Pro Text    |      100 |    |
| SF Pro Rounded Light             | SF-Pro-Rounded-Light.otf            | APPL       | SF Pro Rounded |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Rounded Thin              | SF-Pro-Rounded-Thin.otf             | APPL       | SF Pro Rounded |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Display Semibold          | SF-Pro-Display-Semibold.otf         | APPL       | SF Pro Display |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Display Light             | SF-Pro-Display-Light.otf            | APPL       | SF Pro Display |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Display Thin              | SF-Pro-Display-Thin.otf             | APPL       | SF Pro Display |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Display Regular           | SF-Pro-Display-Regular.otf          | APPL       | SF Pro Display |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Italic                    | SF-Pro-Italic.ttf                   | APPL       | SF Pro         |      100 |    |
| SF Pro Text Thin Italic          | SF-Pro-Text-ThinItalic.otf          | APPL       | SF Pro Text    |      100 |    |
| SF Pro                           | SF-Pro.ttf                          | APPL       | SF Pro         |        0 |    |
| SF Pro                           | SF-Pro.ttf                          | APPL       | SF Pro         |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Text Bold                 | SF-Pro-Text-Bold.otf                | APPL       | SF Pro Text    |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Italic                    | SF-Pro-Italic.ttf                   | APPL       | SF Pro         |      100 |    |
| SF Pro                           | SF-Pro.ttf                          | APPL       | SF Pro         |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Text Regular Italic       | SF-Pro-Text-RegularItalic.otf       | APPL       | SF Pro Text    |      100 |    |
| SF Pro                           | SF-Pro.ttf                          | APPL       | SF Pro         |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Italic                    | SF-Pro-Italic.ttf                   | APPL       | SF Pro         |      100 |    |
| SF Pro Text Medium Italic        | SF-Pro-Text-MediumItalic.otf        | APPL       | SF Pro Text    |      100 |    |
| SF Pro                           | SF-Pro.ttf                          | APPL       | SF Pro         |        0 |    |
| SF Pro                           | SF-Pro.ttf                          | APPL       | SF Pro         |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Rounded Bold              | SF-Pro-Rounded-Bold.otf             | APPL       | SF Pro Rounded |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Display Thin Italic       | SF-Pro-Display-ThinItalic.otf       | APPL       | SF Pro Display |      100 |    |
| SF Pro Text Black                | SF-Pro-Text-Black.otf               | APPL       | SF Pro Text    |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Display Black             | SF-Pro-Display-Black.otf            | APPL       | SF Pro Display |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Rounded Black             | SF-Pro-Rounded-Black.otf            | APPL       | SF Pro Rounded |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Italic                    | SF-Pro-Italic.ttf                   | APPL       | SF Pro         |      100 |    |
| SF Pro Display Semibold Italic   | SF-Pro-Display-SemiboldItalic.otf   | APPL       | SF Pro Display |      100 |    |
| SF Pro                           | SF-Pro.ttf                          | APPL       | SF Pro         |        0 |    |
| SF Pro                           | SF-Pro.ttf                          | APPL       | SF Pro         |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Italic                    | SF-Pro-Italic.ttf                   | APPL       | SF Pro         |      100 |    |
| SF Pro Rounded Medium            | SF-Pro-Rounded-Medium.otf           | APPL       | SF Pro Rounded |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Italic                    | SF-Pro-Italic.ttf                   | APPL       | SF Pro         |      100 |    |
| SF Pro Rounded Regular           | SF-Pro-Rounded-Regular.otf          | APPL       | SF Pro Rounded |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Display Heavy Italic      | SF-Pro-Display-HeavyItalic.otf      | APPL       | SF Pro Display |      100 |    |
| SF Pro Display Ultralight        | SF-Pro-Display-Ultralight.otf       | APPL       | SF Pro Display |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Text Thin                 | SF-Pro-Text-Thin.otf                | APPL       | SF Pro Text    |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Rounded Ultralight        | SF-Pro-Rounded-Ultralight.otf       | APPL       | SF Pro Rounded |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Text Ultralight Italic    | SF-Pro-Text-UltralightItalic.otf    | APPL       | SF Pro Text    |      100 |    |
| SF Pro Display Ultralight Italic | SF-Pro-Display-UltralightItalic.otf | APPL       | SF Pro Display |      100 |    |
| SF Pro Text Semibold             | SF-Pro-Text-Semibold.otf            | APPL       | SF Pro Text    |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Italic                    | SF-Pro-Italic.ttf                   | APPL       | SF Pro         |      100 |    |
| SF Pro Text Heavy Italic         | SF-Pro-Text-HeavyItalic.otf         | APPL       | SF Pro Text    |      100 |    |
| SF Pro Italic                    | SF-Pro-Italic.ttf                   | APPL       | SF Pro         |      100 |    |
| SF Pro Display Medium Italic     | SF-Pro-Display-MediumItalic.otf     | APPL       | SF Pro Display |      100 |    |
| SF Pro Text Bold Italic          | SF-Pro-Text-BoldItalic.otf          | APPL       | SF Pro Text    |      100 |    |
| SF Pro Display Bold Italic       | SF-Pro-Display-BoldItalic.otf       | APPL       | SF Pro Display |      100 |    |
| SF Pro Text Ultralight           | SF-Pro-Text-Ultralight.otf          | APPL       | SF Pro Text    |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Text Black Italic         | SF-Pro-Text-BlackItalic.otf         | APPL       | SF Pro Text    |      100 |    |
| SF Pro Text Medium               | SF-Pro-Text-Medium.otf              | APPL       | SF Pro Text    |        0 |    |
| SF Pro Display Bold              | SF-Pro-Display-Bold.otf             | APPL       | SF Pro Display |        0 |    |
```

### How to quickly identify the string for use with `create-fontset-from-fontset-spec`

```lisp
(require 'dash)
(->> (font-family-list)
     (--filter (string-match-p "SF Pro" it)) ; change the family name, if requried
     -uniq
     (--map
      (cons it
        (if nil       ; flip this to t, for simpler result
        (x-family-fonts it)
          (->> (list-fonts (font-spec :family it))
           (--map (list it :name (or (font-get it :name)
                         (mouse-generate-font-name-for-menu it))
                :xlfd-name (font-xlfd-name it))))))))
```

```lisp
(("SF Pro"
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro nil iso10646-1 medium italic normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Italic.ttf" . 327680))
         > :name "medium italic" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro nil iso10646-1 regular italic normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Italic.ttf" . 0))
         > :name "regular italic" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro-regular-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro nil iso10646-1 thin normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro.ttf" . 65536))
         > :name "thin" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro-thin-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro nil iso10646-1 black normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro.ttf" . 524288))
         > :name "black" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro-black-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro nil iso10646-1 semi-bold normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro.ttf" . 393216))
         > :name "semi-bold" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro-semibold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro nil iso10646-1 regular normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro.ttf" . 0))
         > :name "regular" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro-regular-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro nil iso10646-1 thin normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro.ttf" . 131072))
         > :name "thin" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro-thin-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro nil iso10646-1 light italic normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Italic.ttf" . 196608))
         > :name "light italic" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro-light-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro nil iso10646-1 black normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro.ttf" . 589824))
         > :name "black" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro-black-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro nil iso10646-1 semi-bold italic normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Italic.ttf" . 393216))
         > :name "semi-bold italic" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro-semibold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro nil iso10646-1 bold normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro.ttf" . 458752))
         > :name "bold" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro-bold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro nil iso10646-1 medium normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro.ttf" . 327680))
         > :name "medium" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro nil iso10646-1 black italic normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Italic.ttf" . 524288))
         > :name "black italic" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro-black-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro nil iso10646-1 black italic normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Italic.ttf" . 589824))
         > :name "black italic" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro-black-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro nil iso10646-1 bold italic normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Italic.ttf" . 458752))
         > :name "bold italic" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro-bold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro nil iso10646-1 light normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro.ttf" . 196608))
         > :name "light" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro-light-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro nil iso10646-1 thin italic normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Italic.ttf" . 131072))
         > :name "thin italic" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro-thin-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro nil iso10646-1 thin italic normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Italic.ttf" . 65536))
         > :name "thin italic" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro-thin-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"))
 ("SF Pro Rounded"
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Rounded nil iso10646-1 semi-bold normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Rounded-Semibold.otf" . 0))
         > :name "semi-bold" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Rounded-semibold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Rounded nil iso10646-1 regular normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Rounded-Regular.otf" . 0))
         > :name "regular" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Rounded-regular-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Rounded nil iso10646-1 black normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Rounded-Black.otf" . 0))
         > :name "black" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Rounded-black-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Rounded nil iso10646-1 semi-bold normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Rounded-Bold.otf" . 0))
         > :name "semi-bold" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Rounded-semibold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Rounded nil iso10646-1 extra-bold normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Rounded-Heavy.otf" . 0))
         > :name "extra-bold" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Rounded-extrabold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Rounded nil iso10646-1 light normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Rounded-Light.otf" . 0))
         > :name "light" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Rounded-light-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Rounded nil iso10646-1 medium normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Rounded-Medium.otf" . 0))
         > :name "medium" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Rounded-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Rounded nil iso10646-1 thin normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Rounded-Ultralight.otf" . 0))
         > :name "thin" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Rounded-thin-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Rounded nil iso10646-1 ultra-light normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Rounded-Thin.otf" . 0))
         > :name "ultra-light" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Rounded-ultralight-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"))
 ("SF Pro Display"
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Display nil iso10646-1 ultra-light italic normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Display-ThinItalic.otf" . 0))
         > :name "ultra-light italic" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Display-ultralight-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Display nil iso10646-1 thin normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Display-Ultralight.otf" . 0))
         > :name "thin" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Display-thin-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Display nil iso10646-1 light italic normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Display-LightItalic.otf" . 0))
         > :name "light italic" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Display-light-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Display nil iso10646-1 regular italic normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Display-RegularItalic.otf" . 0))
         > :name "regular italic" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Display-regular-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Display nil iso10646-1 extra-bold italic normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Display-HeavyItalic.otf" . 0))
         > :name "extra-bold italic" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Display-extrabold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Display nil iso10646-1 semi-bold italic normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Display-BoldItalic.otf" . 0))
         > :name "semi-bold italic" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Display-semibold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Display nil iso10646-1 black normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Display-Black.otf" . 0))
         > :name "black" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Display-black-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Display nil iso10646-1 semi-bold normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Display-Semibold.otf" . 0))
         > :name "semi-bold" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Display-semibold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Display nil iso10646-1 medium normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Display-Medium.otf" . 0))
         > :name "medium" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Display-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Display nil iso10646-1 medium italic normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Display-MediumItalic.otf" . 0))
         > :name "medium italic" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Display-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Display nil iso10646-1 regular normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Display-Regular.otf" . 0))
         > :name "regular" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Display-regular-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Display nil iso10646-1 semi-bold normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Display-Bold.otf" . 0))
         > :name "semi-bold" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Display-semibold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Display nil iso10646-1 extra-bold normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Display-Heavy.otf" . 0))
         > :name "extra-bold" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Display-extrabold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Display nil iso10646-1 light normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Display-Light.otf" . 0))
         > :name "light" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Display-light-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Display nil iso10646-1 semi-bold italic normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Display-SemiboldItalic.otf" . 0))
         > :name "semi-bold italic" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Display-semibold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Display nil iso10646-1 thin italic normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Display-UltralightItalic.otf" . 0))
         > :name "thin italic" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Display-thin-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Display nil iso10646-1 black italic normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Display-BlackItalic.otf" . 0))
         > :name "black italic" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Display-black-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Display nil iso10646-1 ultra-light normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Display-Thin.otf" . 0))
         > :name "ultra-light" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Display-ultralight-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1"))
 ("SF Pro Text"
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Text nil iso10646-1 black italic normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Text-BlackItalic.otf" . 0))
         > :name "black italic" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Text-black-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Text nil iso10646-1 extra-bold italic normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Text-HeavyItalic.otf" . 0))
         > :name "extra-bold italic" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Text-extrabold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Text nil iso10646-1 thin italic normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Text-UltralightItalic.otf" . 0))
         > :name "thin italic" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Text-thin-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Text nil iso10646-1 semi-bold italic normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Text-SemiboldItalic.otf" . 0))
         > :name "semi-bold italic" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Text-semibold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Text nil iso10646-1 regular italic normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Text-RegularItalic.otf" . 0))
         > :name "regular italic" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Text-regular-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Text nil iso10646-1 thin normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Text-Ultralight.otf" . 0))
         > :name "thin" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Text-thin-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Text nil iso10646-1 medium italic normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Text-MediumItalic.otf" . 0))
         > :name "medium italic" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Text-medium-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Text nil iso10646-1 medium normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Text-Medium.otf" . 0))
         > :name "medium" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Text-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Text nil iso10646-1 semi-bold italic normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Text-BoldItalic.otf" . 0))
         > :name "semi-bold italic" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Text-semibold-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Text nil iso10646-1 semi-bold normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Text-Bold.otf" . 0))
         > :name "semi-bold" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Text-semibold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Text nil iso10646-1 black normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Text-Black.otf" . 0))
         > :name "black" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Text-black-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Text nil iso10646-1 regular normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Text-Regular.otf" . 0))
         > :name "regular" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Text-regular-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Text nil iso10646-1 ultra-light normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Text-Thin.otf" . 0))
         > :name "ultra-light" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Text-ultralight-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Text nil iso10646-1 light italic normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Text-LightItalic.otf" . 0))
         > :name "light italic" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Text-light-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Text nil iso10646-1 light normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Text-Light.otf" . 0))
         > :name "light" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Text-light-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Text nil iso10646-1 extra-bold normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Text-Heavy.otf" . 0))
         > :name "extra-bold" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Text-extrabold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Text nil iso10646-1 semi-bold normal normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Text-Semibold.otf" . 0))
         > :name "semi-bold" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Text-semibold-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
  (#<font-entity ftcrhb APPL SF\ Pro\ Text nil iso10646-1 ultra-light italic normal 0 nil nil 0
         ((:font-entity "~/.local/share/fonts/SF-Pro-Text-ThinItalic.otf" . 0))
         > :name "ultra-light italic" :xlfd-name "-APPL-SF Pro Text-ultralight-italic-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")))
```

Comment: Thanks for digging into this! A quick try of [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/73067/8373) seems to work! Although I don't fully understand what causes the issue now. I originally think that there maybe something wrong with the `PingFang Mono SC` font (as the issue also exists when it's paired with other variable fonts) and the `:font` part somehow misread its properties as defaults and other faces inherits that (the doc says `:font` sets lots of things). I try to use `:family` instead that that's not working.

Comment: Can you also give me a tl;dr version of how this issue happens :)? I also need some time to read and fully understand your posts.