# `buffer-face-mode` does not work with custom fontset

Tags: faces, fonts, fontsets

I can not change family and size of a custom fontset in `buffer-face-mode`. Below is the minimal test config

```
(create-fontset-from-fontset-spec
 (font-xlfd-name (font-spec :registry "fontset-mine" :family "SF Pro"
                :weight 'regular :slant 'normal :width 'normal)))

(defun org-mode-set-face ()
  ;; (buffer-face-set :family "SF Pro" :height 1.50) ; works
  (buffer-face-set :family "fontset-mine" :height 1.50)) ; does not work
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'org-mode-set-face)
```

[image]

(Note that `describe-char` on `t` of `texts` shows that it uses a different font instead.)

- Emacs version: `GNU Emacs 28.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin21.5.0, Carbon Version 165 AppKit 2113.5) of 2022-07-0`
- OS: macOS 12.5 (21G72)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```lisp
(create-fontset-from-fontset-spec
 (font-xlfd-name
  (font-spec
   :registry "fontset-mine"
   :family "SF Pro"
   :weight 'regular
   :slant 'normal
   :width 'normal)))

(defface my-face nil "My Face.")

(set-face-attribute 'my-face nil
                    :font "fontset-mine"
                    :height 1.0)

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (defun my-org-mode-hook ()
            (buffer-face-set 'my-face)
            (face-remap-add-relative 'my-face
                                     :height 1.5)))
```

Instead of rolling out your own `my-face`, you can as well work with `variable-pitch` face.  IOW, you can get the same effect by

- setting the `:font` property on `variable-pitch` face
- put the `org` buffer in `variable-pitch-mode`
- do a `face-remap-add-relative` as above

Before putting `org` buffers in `variable-pitch-mode` I suggest that you consult prior work like this one [Ricing up Org Mode](https://lepisma.xyz/2017/10/28/ricing-org-mode/)

Comment: Both ways work like a charm. Thank you! You're a face expert!